# Switch user session programmatically

Tags: 8, users, sessions

I'm trying to switch user session thanks to Drupal Switch. I want to do this so that when I have a certain role, I can switch to another user account to check some data from the user i choose to switch.

My routing :

```
double_vue.page_double_vue:
    path: '/double-vue'
    defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\double_vue\Controller\DoubleVueController::doubleVue'
        _title: 'Double vue'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
double_vue.switched_user:
    path: '/double-vue/{userSwitchedID}'
    defaults:
        _controller: '\Drupal\double_vue\Controller\DoubleVueController::switchUser'
        _title: 'UserSwitched'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

My view :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ path('double_vue.switched_user', { 'userSwitchedID': "15" }) }}">switch</a>
```

My function :

```
  public function switchUser($userSwitchedID){
    $accountSwitcher = \Drupal::service('account_switcher');
    $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userSwitchedID);
    return $accountSwitcher->switchTo($account);
  }
```

When I click on my to link to switch to another user, I have this error in my logs :

> The controller must return a response
>   (Object(Drupal\Core\Session\AccountSwitcher) given)

If I remove the return, I have this :

> The controller must return a response (null given)

How can I fix that so that I can switch to another user account ?

Comment: You _have_ switched to a different user account - but you also need to return a response for the request. Could be a normal page, a redirect, even a binary file download - but you'll need to return a response

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: Return whatever response you need to - I couldn't tell you what that is, obviously, it's your requirement :)

Comment: I don't realy know, I have a "super user" who needs to have access to other user account by my view, I understood that I need to use the switch, but I don't what does this should return

Comment: Well what's the user supposed to see? What page are they supposed to be on after they've hit this URL? Return a redirect response to that URL

Comment: He's supposed to have access to other user's informations through view. It's like to have 2 sessions connected at the same time

Comment: That's impossible, at best you'd have to stash the old one and offer a way to switch back (like the Masquerade module does, for example).

Comment: Yes I need exactly something like masquerade, but with a frontend with all my users in a list and next to each user, the button like masquerade

Comment: You'll need to do some development yourself for that. If/when you get a specific question, that's when to ask here

Comment: I tried something, that's why I'm here ^^'

Comment: The question you've asked has been answered, you need to ask a new question for next problem. There's no way you'll get a tutorial of how to build the entire functionality of the Masquerade module in a single question, it's not how this site is structured. If you break all of your tasks down and when you get stuck at any point, ask a single, narrowly-scoped question each time, you'll be able to build your own tutorial, while respecting the ethos of the site at the same time

Answer (score 1):

So first, the account switcher is for a temporary switch in the same request, to execute a specific thing as another user, it can't be used for what you want.

What [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade) does is a lot more complicated and I don't understand why you don't just use that. Masquerade automatically adds itself to the user operations, so if you build a view that lists your users with the operations field then you will have exactly what you want to do.

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with
>   enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no
>   password required). That person can switch back to their own user
>   account at any time.